# Solved: If extension does not have adminhtml.xml and Adminhtml folder, how to solve 404?

Tags: extensions, patches, magento-1.9.2.0

After applying patch 6788, I know that config.xml must be edited. My extension does not have the Adminhtml folder and its xml file, so after making changes still I'm getting 404. Below is the config.xml. What would be the correct "action" statement?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <J_G>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </J_G>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <g>
                <class>J_G_Helper</class>
            </g>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <j_g>
                <class>J_G_Block</class>
            </j_g>
        </blocks>
    </global>


    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <J_G after="Mage_Adminhtml">J_G_Adminhtml</J_G>
                    <frontName>g</frontName>
                </modules> 
            </args> 
        </adminhtml> 
    </routers> 
</admin> 

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <gr>
                <children>
                    <custom translate="title" module="g">
                        <title>Custom</title>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <sales translate="title" module="g">
                                <title>Sales</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <top translate="title" module="g">
                                        <title>Payment Method</title>
                                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                        <action>adminhtml/g_sales_paymentmethod</action>
                                    </top>
                                </children>
                            </sales>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                </children>
            </gr>
        </menu>....
```

Comment: When you register your admin router after Mage_Adminhtml, there is no need to have that extra frontname. Path you have specified in menu action, will be resolved into controllers/G/Sales/PaymentmethodController.php file, make sure you have that in place.

Comment: Can  you pleas tell me location of controller (admincontroller files)

Comment: J/G/controllers/Sales/Paymentmethodcontrollers.php is the path

Comment: after the controllers path I think you also need Adminhtml

Comment: But there is no adminhtml.xml? Would it matter? I'm not good in extensions

Comment: I made this path J/G/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Payment.ethodcontrollers.php but still 404 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You action should be

- `adminhtml/sales_paymentmethod/YourActionName`

from

- `adminhtml/g_sales_paymentmethod`

**Rules:**

***adminRouterName/Lowecase(ClassNameFromAdminhtmlFolderTOController)/ActionName***

Update

**Your controller path should be**

```
../J/G/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/PaymentmethodController.php
```

Class should name should be

- `J_G_Adminhtml_Sales_PaymentmethodController`

Comment: Almost there...I created the Adminhtml folder in controllers and put the subfolders in it.From where I should get the "ActionName"? I got this error "Controller file was loaded but class does not exist"

Comment: please check update

Answer (score 0):

```
<routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <G before="Mage_Adminhtml">J_G_Adminhtml</G>
                </modules> 
            </args> 
        </adminhtml> 
    </routers>`
```

I think?

Comment: It did not work for me! How about the action?

Comment: I would take a look at here https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox , see how he fixes extensions and copy that method

Comment: I have done that but it did not help, as it does not create Adminhtml folder if needed